# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k_folds'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Python 3.6.3 Version and `sklearn.__version__ '0.20.3'`
I have a Problem with `__INIT__`

```py
#cv = KFold(len(X), k_folds=6, shuffle=True)
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
cv = StratifiedKFold(len(X), k_folds=6, shuffle=True)
results = []
y_pred_list = []
```

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k_folds'
```

Comment: `k_folds` does not appear to be one of the parameters for that class: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html

Comment: Welcome to SO; the documentation is your best friend, and it is highly advisable to consult it before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) there are only 3 accepted parameters:

- `n_splits`: `int`
- `shuffle`: `bool`
- `random_state`: `int`

Did you mean to use `n_splits` instead of `k_folds`?

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_folds'

Comment: @ReddyprasadeE As I said in the answer, you should probably use `n_splits` instead of `k_folds`.

Answer (score 0):

`class sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=’warn’, shuffle=False, random_state=None)`

There is no such parameter as `k_folds` in this class

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_folds'

Comment: It is because this `__init__` does not accept any other value than: `n_splits`, `shuffle` or `random_state`. You cant use `k_folds` or `n_folds`.